# Z Transform of n-varying function

Tags: z-transform

I've been doing some reading on z-transforms and I'm still fairly new to the topic. I understand finding the transforms very basic signals.

But the *approach* to finding the transform of this following one threw me off

[image]

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with the defintion, treating the two domains as separate Z transforms that are being added together:

$$X_2(z) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{-n} z^{-n} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n} z^{-n}$$

Some simple initial manipulations yield:

$$X_2(z) =-1 + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n} z^{n} + \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n} z^{-n}$$

Comment: Following that I gather the the transform would be z/(z -.5) + z/(z- .333)  with a region of convergence of .333 < |Z| < .5   This sound about right?

Comment: Oh, I don't know.  You just asked for an approach. :)  Be careful about the sign of the exponent of $z$ in the one summation.  Also don't forget the -1 out front.